# Spring quartz configuration

Tags: spring, quartz

I need your help please:

i have a spring batch app that is running perfectly with the main job and step as shown below :

```
@Bean

       public Job JobFinal(Step step1) {

           return jobBuilderFactory

                   .get("JobFinal")

                   .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())

                   .start(step1)

                   .build();

       }

    

       @Bean

       public Step step1()  {

           return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<A, B>chunk(2)

                   .reader(readerDB())

                   .processor(process())

                   .writer(writerCS())

                   .build();

       }
```

this job is configured in a class "BatchConfig" :

And here is my main :

```
public class DemoApplication {


public static void main(String[] args) {



   SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

   

}
```

}

I want to add quartz configuration to run the job everyday at midnight.

I couldn't find helpful tutorial to understand how to configure quartz in my case and in which class exactly !

Thank you for helpp :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use SchedulerFactory for automatically triggering the jobs using Quartz like below:

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sche = sf.getScheduler();

JobDetail job = newJob(myclass.class).withIdentity("myid", "myname").build();
CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("mytriggerid", "myname").withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 * * *"))
.build();
sche.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
sche.start();
```

Official documentation:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html